# problem with camelcase field model in yii2

Tags: php, model, yii2, field, camelcasing

I built a project with Yii2 a year ago, I created more than ten models of the project, and the code has really expanded. My project worked well. And I had no problem.

This year, I had to transfer the database to another server.(connect remote to database) The new server has the following specifications:

**new server:**

server: 20.04.4

mysql:  8.0.21

php: 7.4.7

**Previous server**:
server: 19.0.4

mysql:  5.7.28

php: 7.2.24

The problem is that the fields defined as CamelCase in the database are not identifiable in this project.

How can I use CamelCase fields in a project without renaming the fields in the database?

if I removed 'attributes' => [PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER], from db.php I get  this error:

[image]

Comment: So the fields in database are not camelcased and are only converted to camelcase in-fly? I'm a bit confused

Comment: @Bizley fields in databese are camelcased. in model are camelcased. apparently camelcase fields in new server are not identified.

Comment: Check if this setting is applied on the new machine and play with it, might help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @Bizley I removed 'attributes' => [PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER], from db.php  , but I get Undefined index: constraint_name. I will add more details to my questions.

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/18171 - solution posted by darkdef worked for me